# What is the efficient way to list the unique List[String]'s from an Array[List[String]]?

Tags: scala

I want to find unique `List[String]` from an `Array[List[String]]`.

For example,
suppose we have an `Array` of the following `List[String]`

```
[a, b, c]
[a, b]
[a, b]
[a, c]
```

The expected result would be

```
[a, b, c]
[a, b]
[a, c]
```

Comment: `myALS.distinct`

Comment: Same method you use to find unique *anything* from `Array[anything]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can apply **.distinct** in Array(List(String))

> **def distinct: Array[List[String]]**
>
> Builds a new mutable indexed sequence from this mutable indexed
>   sequence without any duplicate elements.
>
> **Returns**
>
> A new mutable indexed sequence which contains the first occurrence of
>   every element of this mutable indexed sequence.

Try the below snippet

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object StackTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\hadoop")
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .config("spark.master", "local[1]")
      .appName("StackOverFlow")
      .getOrCreate()

    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")

    val hc = spark.sqlContext
    import spark.implicits._

    //Define Array[List[String]]
    var myArrList = Array(List("a","b","c"),List("a","b"),List("a","b"),List("a","c"))
    println("ArrayList: "+ myArrList.deep)

    var distinctMyArrList = myArrList.distinct
    println("Distinct ArrayList: "+ distinctMyArrList.deep)

  }
}
```

OUTPUT

```
ArrayList: Array(List(a, b, c), List(a, b), List(a, b), List(a, c))
Distinct ArrayList: Array(List(a, b, c), List(a, b), List(a, c))
```